# when does an address shows on blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, address, bip32-hd-wallets, ledger-hardware-wallet

I have a ledger wallet which generates several public keys/addresses. Without having used any of them, some of them are shown in blockchain.info whereas other produce an "Unrecognized search pattern" error. Why does that happen? All these addresses come from the same master key.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are checking Bitcoin addresses with blockchain.info (a Bitcoin address from a Ledger Wallet starts with a "1")?

If there has not been sent any bitcoins to an address, then blockchain.info will show it without any transactions and a balance of zero. It should never say "unrecognized search pattern".

Comment: yes, they are pks/addresses produced by the dongle and they start with 1. But some of them are "unrecognized search patterns" by blockchain.info. What are these keys? I also received some bits to the others that do appear at blockchain.info but the amount never appears to my wallet (ledger wallet  interface). Have I lost these payments? I am confused with what these keys are?

Comment: Have you tried to lookup the "unrecognized" addresses with e.g. blockr.io just to make sure it is not a problem with blockchain.info? Otherwise can you public one of those addresses here?

Comment: you were right. now almos all of them appear at  http://blockr.io but I still have one address that is not shown.. the address is 1PYJ3cY9hDu8Gshzp7aN9z8SyhDY5gT5PBnþ .. what is that?

Comment: You know that you have a special symbol at the end of the address you posted, which is not part of an address? I can find the address here: https://blockr.io/address/info/1PYJ3cY9hDu8Gshzp7aN9z8SyhDY5gT5PBn

Comment: oh thank you so much! So, I tried to send some bits to some of these "weird" addresses, but the amount does not show on my wallet. Do you have any idea why that happens? I am a bit afraid of using that particular wallet now, as the amount sent to these addresses does not show.

Comment: Sending bits to "weird" addresses is not possible, since an address contains a checksum which makes sure that there are not typus (such as weird characters) in the address. You have to sent the amount (again) to the correctly spelled addresses.

Comment: but I can see the transaction online as well as the balance of these addresses, but that balance does not appear to my wallet? Am I missing something here? For instance, I have sent 0.05 bits to one of these addresses that my dongle produces, I can see the trasnaction online, but thse 0.05 bits do not appear to the balance that its shown by my wallet..